# cant open enc format files transfared from android phone to pc

Tags: android, iphone, mobile-phone

I transferred my images from the phone to desktop pc running with windows and some of the files have .enc format and i can't open them because of that. how can I solve this please?

Answer (score 0):

The images that you are trying to open are encrypted files. The easiest way to open the encrypted files is by accessing the program or proprietary utility that encrypted them from the phone. The original file will be something like filename.jpg and the encoded file is filename.jpg.enc.

Since the images were sent to you from your sister, you should tell her to unencrypt the images with her iPhone and resend you the unencrypted images. This would be much easier to do than trying to crack the password of the encrypted images from your Windows computer.

Comment: This images are sent to me from my sister, she probably done some of them using applications in iphone. Is there a way to open them without this procedure you talk about? It's not a large amount of files(15-20), but you know... this is memory...

Comment: Ok, thanks Karel. I guess this won't be done as she sent it a long time ago and we don't even know what application did she use to make this images